# Opendaylight API can't select node for creating flow

Tags: opendaylight, mininet, sdn

I'm new to SDN and I'm trying the opendaylight controller.
I have set it up with running web API and I can't add flows but it recognizes my topology.

I use mininet to create the topology.
Opendaylight helium 2.0.

Does anybody know why i can't select nodes to create my flow?
Here are some images:

[Opendaylight can't select node to create flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLpNp.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, there seem to be more people with the same problem. Here you can find an answer:

 https://ask.opendaylight.org/question/862/static-flow/

They say that it's better to use the REST Interface.

Comment: Hello, Ana. Welcome to SO. Even if the link provides an answer, it is considered a good practice to include the solution itself inside the answer. :)